Flutter Socket.IO connection not working with domain URL
I'm facing an issue while trying to establish a Socket.IO connection in my Flutter app using a domain URL. When I use the domain (e.g., https://example.com), the connection doesn't work. However, it works perfectly with the IP address (e.g., https://123.456.789.101:1234).
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as io;
import '../../data/network/api_constants.dart';
import 'db_helper.dart';

class SocketHelper {
  static final SocketHelper _singleton = SocketHelper._internal();

  SocketHelper._internal();

  factory SocketHelper() => _singleton;

  late io.Socket _socketIO;

  bool isConnected = false, isUserConnected = false;

  void init() {
    _socketIO = io.io(
        ApiConstants.socketUrl,
        io.OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket']) // for Flutter or Dart VM
            .enableAutoConnect()
            .setExtraHeaders({'forceNew': true})
            .build());
    _socketIO.disconnect().connect();

    _initListener();
  }

  _initListener() {
    _socketIO.onConnect((data) {
      isConnected = true;
      if (DbHelper().getUserModel()?.id != null) {
        connectUser();
      }
      debugPrint("data========sss==========>$data");
    });
    _socketIO.onConnectError((data) {
      isConnected = false;
      debugPrint("onConnectError ===============>${data.toString()}");
    });
    _socketIO.onError((data) {
      debugPrint(data.toString());
    });

    //--------------------------------Connect User Listener -------------------------//

    _socketIO.on(ApiConstants.connectUser, (data) {
      isUserConnected = true;
      //socketGlobalListeners();
      debugPrint("user connected : $data");
    });
  }

  io.Socket getSocket() => _socketIO;

//--------------------------------Connect User Emitter -------------------------//

  connectUser() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = HashMap();
    map['userId'] = DbHelper().getUserModel()?.id ?? "";
    _socketIO.emit(ApiConstants.connectUser, map);
    debugPrint("_socketIO=================${_socketIO.connected}");
    debugPrint("_socketIO============map=====$map");
  }
}

